# mongoose aggregate() will not return the correct value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongodb aggregate(). When I was trying it from Mongo shell, it worked fine like the following code:

```
> db.trics.aggregate( [ {$group: {_id: "$club", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$sort: {count: -1}}, {$limit: 1} ] )
{ "_id" : 0, "count" : 2 }
```

But, when I moved the same aggregation operation to my server backed by Mongoose,

```
Object.aggregate([ {$group: {_id: "$club", count: {$sum: 1}}} ]).sort('-count').limit(1)
```

the "_id" of the $group result was always returning "null": What I got from postman

```
[ { _id: null, count: 2 } ]
```

Could any Mongo/Mongoose expert help me out of this please?

Many thanks

FYI:  the "Object" document example:

```
{
  "_id" : 0,  // auto increment primary key for "Object" collection
  club" : 0,  // auto increment primary key for "Club" collection
}
```

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: hi, it's version 3.2.4 (db version v3.2.4)

Comment: I test your codes under mongoose v4.4.3, and the return value is `[ { _id: 1, count: 2 } ]` same as the result of mongo shell...

Comment: Thank you @zangw, yes, I found it's a bug from other part of my code. Many thanks for your help. My mistake!